# How could outcomes be equally likely?

Tags: probability, combinations

Hi I've just started learning probability but I have some questions.
When sloving a problem like "If 3 balls are “randomly drawn” from a bowl containing 6 white and 5 black balls, what is the probability that one of the balls is white and the other two black?" , they assume outcomes in the sample space are equally likely. However when considering picking 2 balls from 2 white and 1000000 black balls, how could (w,w) (w,b) be (b,b) (unordered) considered equally likely? 
In my opinion (b,b) are much more likely than (w,w) because there are way much black balls than white balls. 
Of course their numbers are considered when solving the probability, I still wonder   is it valid that (w,w) (w,b) be (b,b) be assumed equally likely.

Sorry for my bad english because i'm not a native speaker. Please excuse me. Thank you.

-edited

In a textbook, it says that "When the experiment consists of a random selection of k items from a set of n items, we have the flexibility of either letting the outcome of the experiment be the ordered selection of the k items or letting it be the unordered set of items selected. In the former case we would assume that each new selection is equally likely to be any of the so far unselected items of the set, and ***in the latter case we would assume that all (n k) possible subsets of k items are equally likely to be the set selected***." I'm curious about emphasied part.

Comment: Who are "they"?

Comment: To resolve your confusion, examine the definition of "sample space" more closely. That is, your sample space isn't simply just $\{(w,w),(w,b),(b,b)\}$, but instead, contains all $(w_i,w_j),(b_i,w_j),(w_i,b_j),(b_i,b_j)$ pairs, and they are assumed equally likely, in your context?

Comment: I can either win the lottery first prize, or not win it. Since there are only two outcomes, is the chance I win the lottery $\frac{1}{2}$? Hopefully this should help resolve your confusion.

Comment: I'm sorry for any confusions. In 2.5 of a Ross' textbook, when sloving the problem, the author assumes 11C3 outcomes equally likely at which I have confused. How could (w,w,w), .... (b,b,b) be equally likely when the number of black balls are bigger than of white one? I think I can understand when it is considered as ordered n-tuple but I cannot understand it is unordered. But the textbook says concerning this kind of problem, we have the flexibility of either letting the outcome of the experiment be the ordered selection of the k items or letting it be the unordered set of items selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in saying that the probability of pulling (b,b) is more likely. This is because there are indeed more ways to choose two black balls than two balls in which one is white.

When they say "all" outcomes are equally likely, they are referring to each individual outcome in which two balls are withdrawn regardless of their color. This may become more clear if we consider a simple example...

For example, if we have $2$ green balls in a bag and $4$ red balls in a bag, we can imagine our bag as a set $\{g_1,g_2,r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4\}$. If we were to choose ONE ball randomly from the bag, this would mean we choose them in such a way that every ball has an equal probability of being chosen, despite its color. In order words, we are as likely to choose $g_1$ as we are to choose $g_2$ as we are to choose $r_1$ as we are to choose... i.e.

$$P(g_1)=P(g_2)=P(r_1)=P(r_2)=P(r_3)=P(r_4)$$

However, if you wanted the probability of a green ball being chosen, now I must count the number outcomes that satisfy this criteria and divide it by the total number of outcomes. In effect,

$$P(g_1 \vee g_2)=\frac{2}{6}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Suddenly probability of choosing green is not the same as choosing red. But that is because initially, when we said each outcome was equally likely, we were referring to each individual outcome, which was a ball, regardless of its color.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I could understand when we are considering ordered outcome. However in a textbook, in this kind of experiment, it says we can assume unordered outcomes be equally likely in this case (w,w) (w,b) (b,b).  I guess this kind of assumption could be valid because when solve the probability, the number of (w,b) are multiplied so it's same problem concerning outcomes are ordered but how vary this generalization could be used?

Answer (score 3):

In this context the equiprobable outcomes must be looked at as 3-sets of (distinguishable) balls.

Think of the balls as numbered: $1,2,3,4,5,6$ are white and $7,8,9,10,11$ are black.

Then an outcome by drawing $3$ balls without replacement is e.g. $\{5,2,9\}$.

There are $\binom{6+5}3=165$ of such outcomes and each of them has probability $\frac1{165}$.

We can define $W$ as the number of white balls that is drawn and $B$ as the number of black balls that is drawn, and $W,B$ must then be looked at as random variables on the outcome space.

If  $\omega=\{5,2,9\}$ then $W(\omega)=2$ and $B(\omega)=1$.

---

Also it is possible to go for $3$-tuples here.

Then there will be $11\times10\times9=990$ equiprobable outcomes.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But when outcomes are looked at as tuples, are outcomes there 11*10*9? And sorry I can't say anything about random variables cuz   I haven't studied random variables.

Comment: You are correct and I made a mistake there. Looking at them as sets will do better here because the order of drawing is not relevant and secondly it is without replacement (so every outcome is a set having $3$ elements). Further the equiprobability of the outcomes is not damaged. I will adapt my answer. Sorry for confusion I caused.

Comment: Just ignore what I said about random variables then. That will become clear later if you persist in studying probability (good luck with that).

Comment: Thanks! I'll be right back when I finish my study.